# How to read constants from a shell script in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a bash script which has:

```
SUCCESS="0"
FAIL="1"
DEBUG="TRUE"
```

Is it possible to read this in a python script? Something like source.

Comment: Well, what you show is valid Python as well; you could just import it.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question has already been: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list)

```
>>> with open("C:/.../tmp.sh") as f:
        content = f.readlines()
>>> content = [x.strip() for x in content]
```

Insert into the dictionary and remove quotes if necessary:

```
>>> import re
>>> divInDict = [{x.split("=")[0]:re.findall(r'"(.*?)"', x.split("=")[1])[0]} for x in content]
```

Output:

```
>>> divInDict 
[{'SUCCESS': '0'}, {'FAIL': '1'}, {'DEBUG': 'TRUE'}]
```

P.S.
I only have python 3 so I additionally tested it in python 2 online:
[enter link description here](https://repl.it/repls/SplendidNocturnalPlots)